# entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an web application in Asp.net with Entity Framework 6 and database first. I'm having issue when it come for the user to connect.Here's my code:

**Web.config**

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=MyServer\MyDataBase;initial catalog=Cliniciel_WebRV_Master;User Id=XXX;Password=XXXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="Cliniciel_WebRV_MasterEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Entities.Cliniciel_WebRV_Master.csdl|res://*/Models.Entities.Cliniciel_WebRV_Master.ssdl|res://*/Models.Entities.Cliniciel_WebRV_Master.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MyServer\MyDataBase;initial catalog=Cliniciel_WebRV_Master;user id=XXX;password=XXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  <add name="Cliniciel_WebRV_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Entities.Cliniciel_WebRV_Entities.csdl|res://*/Models.Entities.Cliniciel_WebRV_Entities.ssdl|res://*/Models.Entities.Cliniciel_WebRV_Entities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MyServer\MyDataBase;initial catalog=Cliniciel_WebRV_DEV;user id=XXX;password=XXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  <add name="Cliniciel_WebRV_Oauth" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Entities.Cliniciel_WebRV_Oauth.csdl|res://*/Models.Entities.Cliniciel_WebRV_Oauth.ssdl|res://*/Models.Entities.Cliniciel_WebRV_Oauth.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MyServer\MyDataBase;initial catalog=Cliniciel_WebRV_Master;user id=XXX;password=XXXX;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />          
 </connectionStrings>
```

Here I use the connection string "Cliniciel_WebRV_Oauth" for my identity authentification.

I configure my oauthToken on startup

**Startup.cs**

```
   private void ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //// Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            //app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                //For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
                #if DEBUG
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                #endif
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
                AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat("http://localhost:55555/")

            };

            // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        }

 private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            var issuer = "http://localhost:55555/";
            string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
            byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]);

            // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                    {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
                    }
                });
        }
```

**ApplicationDBContext.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using WebRV.Models.Entities;

namespace WebRV.Infrastructure
{

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>  //DOIT CREER APPLICATION USER.
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("Cliniciel_WebRV_Oauth", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

    }
}
```

**CustomOAuthProvider.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using WebRV.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebRV.Models.Entities;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;


namespace WebRV.Providers
{

    public class CustomOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
                var allowedOrigin = "*";

                context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

                var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

                ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");

                }
                else
                {

                    //if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
                    //{
                    //    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "User did not confirm email.");
                    //    return;
                    //}


                    ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, "JWT");

                    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, null);

                    context.Validated(ticket);
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Here's the error i got:

> The ApplicationUser entity type is not part of the model for the
>   current context.

here's the trace:

> Ligne 32 :                 var userManager =
>   context.OwinContext.GetUserManager(); Ligne 33
>   :  Ligne 34 :                 ApplicationUser user = await
>   userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password); Ligne 35 : 
>   Ligne 36 :                 if (user == null)
>
> Fichier source : c:\Users\aboucher\Desktop\WebRV-2016-05-12 -
>   Copie\Cliniciel_WebRV\WebRV\WebRV\Providers\CustomOAuthProvider.cs
>   Ligne : 34
>
> Trace de la pile:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Le type d'entité ApplicationUser ne fait
>   pas partie du modèle pour le contexte actuel.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type
>   entityType) +4479799
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +37
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   +16    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   +39    System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   +154    System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate) +163
>
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext()
>   +807    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +28    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +123    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<FindAsync>d__12.MoveNext() +601
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +28    WebRV.Providers.d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Users\aboucher\Desktop\WebRV-2016-05-12 -
>   Copie\Cliniciel_WebRV\WebRV\WebRV\Providers\CustomOAuthProvider.cs:34 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.d__3f.MoveNext()
>   +863    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +28    Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.<InvokeTokenEndpointAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
>   +2336    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.<InvokeAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +1733    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +28    Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +664    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__0.MoveNext() +641    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__0.MoveNext() +641    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__5.MoveNext()
>   +287    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__2.MoveNext()
>   +272    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +26    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Infrastructure.ErrorState.Rethrow() +33 
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +150
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +42
>   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +380    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Please translate that error message to English and post it as text into the question; you'll get more help that way.

Comment: @Alex Is it more clear now?

Comment: Better. Also include line where it throws the exception.

Comment: there are so many QAs about `not part of current context` on StackOverflow. Did you check them already all for an answer?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Yes but all of them didn't not fix my problem :(

Comment: Shouldn't you be accessing your UserManager with ApplicationDbContext instead of OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

where is your ApplicationUserManager Method

you need to configure Application UserManager Like this by passing DbContext

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<EducationContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

most important is to write this line(First Line in Create method)

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<EducationContext>()));
```